# type(4) == type(int) is False in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, types, integer

I tried `type(4) == type(int)`, which returns `False`, but `print type(4)` returns `<type 'int'>`, so 4 is obviously `int`.

Confused why the first statement returns `False` and not `True`?

Comment: `type(int)` is `type`...

Comment: @MartijnPieters, nice catch and vote up. But how to check if the type is int for a number? I want to distinguish between int, float/double and non-numeric.

Comment: @LinMa isinstance(num,int)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `type` of `int` is *type itself*:

```
>>> type(int)
<type 'type'>
```

You'd compare with `int` **directly**; `int` is, after all, a type, as we established above:

```
>>> type(4) == int
True
```

or even, since `int` is a singleton, like all types should be:

```
>>> type(4) is int
True
```

However, the proper way to test for types is to use the [`isinstance()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
>>> isinstance(4, int)
True
```

`isinstance()` also allows for *any subclasses* of `int` to pass this test; a subcclass is always considered to be *at least* an `int`. That includes any custom subclasses you could build yourself, and still have it work as an `int` everywhere else in your code.

Comment: I've learned the same (prefer `isinstance` over `type()==`); however, reading this, the `type(number)==int` *feels* more pythonic. If you could have a word about why `isinstance` is the proper way, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Look this:

```
>>> type(int)
<type 'type'>
>>> type(4)
<type 'int'>
```

Yu should use:

```
>>> isinstance(4,int)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python, type `int` itself is also a object whose type is `type`. So `type(int)` is `type`. On the other hand, `type(4)` is `int`

So if you want to check if `type(4)` is type `int`, you should write as

```
type(4) == int
```

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing `int` with `type(int)`, instead you should:

```
type(4) == int
```

Answer (score 2):

The `type of int` is `type`
and `type of 4` is `int`.

```
>>> type(int)
<type 'type'>
>>> type(4)
<type 'int'>
```

So you doing wrong comparison.
What you can do to get the desired output is:
Compare the `type of 4` with `int`

```
>>> type(4) == int
True
```

Or you can use `is` operator for this like

```
>>> type(4) is int
True
```